# GSOAP data length restrictions in UTF8 strings

Tags: xml, validation, utf-8, gsoap

I'm implementing an Web services server using GSOAP (2.8.14).

The web service uses UTF-8 enconding (SOAP_C_UTFSTRING flag is set). Everything works fine except for XML data length validation.

My questions is if the data length validation that GSOAP performs checks the number of characters or the number of bytes. 
I think it should check characters, but I don't know it this is right.

In my web service, a simple type (string based) is defined with a data length restriction. If the client uses only "ASCII" characters for the element the validation admits the number of characters especified in the restriction.  If the element includes other characters ( for instance "euro symbol") the number of characters admited are fewer.

I would like to know if this is the right behaviour or a bug.

Thank you.